# Changing a filename format from ‘2020-12-09’ to ‘2020.12.09’

Tags: bash, shell-script, date

I’ve figured out how to add a date to the beginning of my files using Bash. The issue is I use the format `2020.12.09 - filename` for all my files historically and prefer it. The command I have adds the date in the standard format of `2020-12-09filename`. I’m looking to replace the dashes with full-stops and to add a dash with surrounding spaces between the date and filename.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include the command you’re using currently, you’ll get a better answer.

Comment: I would do it the other way around, rename your old files to the superior format. Dashes is in line with ISO8601, the international date format standard. Many programs (still) have issues with filenames with spaces in them, because space is the historical argument separator, and while there is almost no limitation on where you can put periods in a filename, they are mostly used to signify extensions. IMO, `2020-12-08_filename.ext` is better than `2020.12.08\ filename.ext` in every way.

Comment: What Stephen said. If you have some command that already gives you a filename on a format that is slightly wrong, it may be better to change that than to "fix it" as an extra step at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit your initial program, take a look at `date` man-page

```
date '+%Y.%m.%d'      # -->  2020.12.09
```

In order to rename existing files:

```
prename 's/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/$1.$2.$3 - /' 20*
```

In some Linux distributions `prename` is called `rename`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```bsh
mv 12-34-5.txt 12\.34\.5.txt
```

the syntax is: `mv` `<old name>` `<new name>`

Comment: You don't need the backslashes in the target, as it's not a Regular Expression

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are generating the date like this:

```
$ date -Idate
2020-12-09
```

You can pipe this into `sed` to substitute `-` with `.` using:

```
$ date -Idate | sed 's/-/./g'
2020.12.09
```

Then you can rename your file:

```
mv "$file" $(date -Idate | sed 's/-/./g')\ -\ "$file"
```

Because that's a little verbose, you could just make a function in `~/.bashrc`:

```
function add-date {
  mv "$1" $(date -Idate | sed 's/-/./g')\ -\ "$1"
}
```

Now to demonstrate it works:

```
$ touch file1
$ ls
file1
$ add-date file1
$ ls
'2020.12.09 - file1'
```

Comment: Or use `date +'%Y.%m.%d'` and avoid the `sed` completely

Comment: @roaima Yes, you're absolutely right.  JJoao has that answer already.  I'll keep this in place as-is in case OP is not using `date` at all so he can easily adapt whatever he *is* using.